# Relationship between MO energies in Hartree-Fock theory and the core Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I am looking at Hartree-Fock (HF) theory as presented in Frank Jensen's book "Introduction to Computational Chemistry", Second edition.

The total energy $E$ of the system can be expressed as

$$
E = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} h_i + \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{ij}^{n} (J_{ij} - K_{ij}) + V_{\mathrm{nuc}}\phantom{..................}(1)
$$

where

$$
    h_i = -\frac{1}{2} \nabla^2_i - \sum\limits_{A=1}^{N} \frac{Z_A}{\lvert \mathrm{R}_A - \mathrm{r}_i \rvert} \\
    g_{ij} = \frac{1}{\lvert \mathrm{r}_i - \mathrm{r}_j \rvert} \\
    J_{ij} = \langle\phi_i(1)\phi_j(2) \vert g_{ij} \vert \phi_i(1)\phi_j(2)\rangle \\
    K_{ij} = \langle\phi_i(1)\phi_j(2) \vert g_{ij} \vert \phi_j(1)\phi_i(2)\rangle \\
    V_{\mathrm{nuc}} = \langle\mathbf{\Phi}_{\mathrm{nuc}} \vert \mathbf{V}^{\mathrm{nuc}} \vert \mathbf{\Phi}_{\mathrm{nuc}}\rangle =  V_{\mathrm{nuc}} \langle\mathbf{\Phi}_{\mathrm{nuc}} \vert \mathbf{\Phi}_{\mathrm{nuc}}\rangle
$$

Then later, after having introduced Lagrangian multipliers to carry out the contrained minimization, he expresses the total energy in terms of the MO energies $\epsilon_i$

$$
E = \sum\limits_{i}^n \epsilon_i - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{ij}^n (J_{ij} - K_{ij}) + V_{\mathrm{nuc}}\phantom{..................}(2)
$$

These two expressions for the total energy share the same form, and I am wondering if there is a physical connection between $h_i$ and $\epsilon_i$.

The naïve thing to do now is to equate the two expressions to obtain

$$
\sum\limits_{ij}(J_{ij} - K_{ij}) = \sum\limits_{i}(\epsilon_i - h_i)
$$

and insert back to obtain

$$
E = \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_i(h_i + \epsilon_i)\phantom{..................}(3)
$$

I realize that the $h_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ are not completely independent, due to iterative nature of the way we have to solve these equations.
We have that the Fock operator contains the one-electron core Hamiltonian

$$
\mathbf{F}_i = \mathbf{h}_i + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{j} (\mathbf{J}_j - \mathbf{K}_j)
$$

and that the orbital energies are computed as the expectation value of the Fock operator

$$
\epsilon_i = \langle\phi_i \vert \mathbf{F}_i \vert \phi_i\rangle
$$

so clearly a fully separated representation for these two quantities cannot be found.

So I guess my main question is this: Is my rewriting above formally correct? If so, I suppose it is just another, less explicit way of expression the correction due to the overly repulsive (due to double counting) MO energies?

Comment: Equation 1) can't be correct, the expression for $h_i$ contains an operator, while the left hand side, E, is just a number. You need to take matrix elements of this operator, and do you know that this operator will be diagonal in the basis you have chosen?

Comment: Oh, I have written it as a matrix elements when it should have been  written as the core hamiltonian operator $\mathbf{h}_i$. My bad...

Comment: [Frank Jensen is on Matter Modeling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/361/5) so it might help to ask there.